# Mongodb cluster sudden crashes with read / write concern queries

Tags: mongodb

We have a mongodb cluster with 5 PSA replica sets and one sharded collection. About 3,5 TB of data, 2 billion docs on primaries. Average insert rate: 300rps. Average select rate: 1000rps. Mongodb version 4.0.6. Collection has only one extra unique index, all read queries use one of the indexes (no long running queries).

PROBLEM. Sometimes (4 times in a last 2 month) one of the nodes stops responding to the queries with specified read concern or write concern. The same query without read/write concern executes successfully regardless of doing it locally or through mongos. These queries never execute, no errors, no timeouts even when restarting mongos, that initiate the query.  No errors in mongod logs, no errors in system logs. Restart of this node fixes the problem. Mongodb sees such broken node as normal, rs.status() shows that everything is ok.
Have no idea how to reproduce this problem, much more intense load testing have no results.

We would appreciate any help and suggestions.